# Hello world example for AllocatorAwareContainer

Tags: c++, allocator

I've searched Google and SO, but am surprised not to see a Hello World example of the [AllocatorAwareContainer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/AllocatorAwareContainer) concept. I'm looking for something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename Allocator>
class HeapValue { // Value semantics of one object on the heap.
public:
    explicit HeapValue(const Allocator& alloc = Allocator()) noexcept;
    explicit HeapValue(const T& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
    HeapValue(const HeapValue&);
    HeapValue(const HeapValue&, const Allocator&);
    HeapValue(HeapValue&&);
    HeapValue(HeapValue&&, const Allocator&);
    ~HeapValue();
    HeapValue& operator=(const HeapValue&);
    HeapValue& operator=(HeapValue&&);
    reference operator*() { return *m_ptr; }
    const_reference operator*() const { return *m_ptr; }
    pointer operator*() { return m_ptr; }
    const_pointer operator*() const { return m_ptr; }
    explicit operator bool() const { return static_cast<bool>(m_ptr); }
private:
    pointer m_ptr;
    allocator_type m_alloc;
};

template <typename T>
using PMRHeapValue = HeapValue<T, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<T>>;

int main() {
    std::byte buffer[64] = {}; // A small buffer on the stack

    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource pool{std::data(buffer), std::size(buffer)};

    PMRHeapValue<std::pmr::vector<int>> opt(&pool);
    opt->push_back(42); // The vector should be using the pool too, right?
    return opt->size();
}
```

I could try fishing through the source for `std::vector` but this seems like the sort of example that should be somewhere. How should this pile of member functions be defined to properly support the AllocatorAwareContainer concept?

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: I updated it. The question is how should this pile of member functions be defined to properly support the AllocatorAwareContainer concept?

Comment: I think just do allocations and deallocations through a stored allocator, take such an allocator as a constructor parameter, and perhaps traffic in allocator member types like ::pointer and ::reference (though I think the standard says this is not strictly necessary, you can just assume they are T* and T&).

Comment: That I get. The part I'm fuzzy about is `select_on_container_copy_construction` and friends, and on transferring the allocator to contained data. I realize now that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LAsqp7UrNs is only talking about `pmr::polymorphic_allocator<>` so I may have the wrong idea about when allocators are passed into child objects.

Comment: I've looked more at this. It seems like part of the magic of propagating the allocator is done by `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<T>::new_object` which uses `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<T>::construct`. So what I want to know is: How do I use a `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<>` to create a `std::pmr::vector<int>` on the heap (to get a  `std::pmr::vector<int>*`), and to correctly destruct and free it?